# The social media logos in my footer are not lining up horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to have the two social media logos appear horizontal, but for some reason “display: inline-block;”  is not working. I have tried moving the display property to social instead of social img and it still wont budge. If possible, can someone please explain what i am doing wrong or missing.

```css
.copyright{
    padding: 2% 4%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.social{
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2%;
}

.social img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    padding:2%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="copyright">
            <p>&copy; Copyright 2022. All Rights Reserved</p>
            <p><a href="mailto:Forwardfitness@club.net">Forwardfitness@club.net</a></p>
    </div>
        
    <div class="social">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fwdfitclub" target="_blank"><img src="facebook-logo.png" alt="black and white facebook logo" ></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/fwdfitclub" target="_blank" ><img src="twitter-logo.png" alt="black and white twitter logo" ></a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float` and set `flex` on `footer` with `align-items: center;`.

```css
.copyright {
  padding: 2% 4%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.social {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2%;
}

.social img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2%;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="copyright">
    <p>&copy; Copyright 2022. All Rights Reserved</p>
    <p><a href="mailto:Forwardfitness@club.net">Forwardfitness@club.net</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fwdfitclub" target="_blank"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/000/fff" alt="black and white facebook logo"></a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/fwdfitclub" target="_blank"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/000/fff" alt="black and white twitter logo"></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your `<img>` tag is wrapped by `<a></a>`
Perhaps you could try this

```
.social a{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` for lining up horizontally the elements (.social and footer)
So:

```css
footer,
.social,
.copyright {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}
```